# Why are my discord.py events not being called?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking to make a bot come online whenever a user joins a channel and go offline when a user leaves a channel. I'm quite new to discord.js but here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
    print("Bot ready")

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        if after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 1""] or after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 2""]:
            await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="users | Ready to mute"))
            print("Bot done0")
            print(member, "joined")

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        if before.channel.id == [""Channel ID 1""] or before.channel.id == [""Channel ID 2""]:
            await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
            print("Bot done1")
            print(member, "left")
```

I will of course replace ""Channel ID 1""  & ""Channel ID 2"" with the channel IDs.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 'def' named: "on_voice_state_update", so when this event happened, the bot doesn't know which one he has to call. Remove one of the 2 'def' and do what you want in only one 'def' named: "on_voice_state_update".

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        if after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 1""] or after.channel.id == [""Channel ID 2""]:
            await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="users | Ready to mute"))
            print("Bot done0")
            print(member, "joined")
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
            if before.channel.id == [""Channel ID 1""] or before.channel.id == [""Channel ID 2""]:
                await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)
                print("Bot done1")
                print(member, "left")
```